# Почему мы продаем "вразвес" и "на развес"?

Tags: орфография

На столбе объявление: "Продаем корма в развес", которое меня вполне устраивает. Однако Грамота.ру со мной не согласна и предлагает слитное написание - вразвес. Итак, мы можем: купить в складчину, в рассрочку, в кредит, продавать (торговать)  в разлив, на развес, в розницу, но мы должны продавать навынос, вразвес. Это можно как-то объяснить?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Мне бы хотелось обсудить всю группу наречий. Можно ли  ориентироваться на следующее утверждение в качестве исходного тезиса: слитно пишутся наречия, в которых приставка используется при их образовании (указать способ образования). Раздельно пишутся наречные выражения (обстоятельственные существительные),  в которых предлог участвует в управлении падежом.

Answer (score 1):

Грамота говорит, что "на развес" нежелательно говорить, надо "на вес". Видимо,считается, что вразвес-уже окончательно наречие, нельзя поставить вопрос "во что?",только "как?",слово "развес"как самостоятельное существительное выходит из употребления.На что?-на вес, на развес ещё воспринимается как сущ. с предлогом.Пусть разговорное. А с предлогом в - нет. Наречия с "В" пишутся слитно, если дальше следует согласный и нельзя вставить определение или вопрос.

Хотя я тоже "в развес" (во что?) воспринимаю нормально.

Answer (score 0):

"(В)развес", мне кажется, срастается в наречие быстрее аналогов, испытывая влияние морфологически схожих, уже прочно сросшихся образований из технического языка, отличающихся узким, строго определённым лексическим значением от исходных  словосочетаний- "вразнос", "вразвал" , "враздрай", "вразброс"...

Comment: У нас много наречных выражений с раздельным написанием:   в меру, в ногу, на износ, под уклон. в струнку, в ряд, в прах, на славу.в заключение, в придачу, в насмешку. в новинку, на зависть, на вкус и др. Им тоже грозит неминуемое срастание в наречия со слитным написанием, дело только во времени?Или еще в чем-то? И что такое "строго определенное лексическое значение", вы термины имеете в виду? Так все наречия этой темы похожи на термины, но большинство из них пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

По причине ненадлежащего качества смазочного масла, выйдя на повышенные обороты, двигатель пошёл вразнос" и "На День города предприятиями общественного питания осуществляется выездная торговля, в том числе торговля в разнос": значения совсем разные, замена невозможна. "Вразнос" уже в советское время подвергся новой метафоризации, просочившись из технического употребления в просторечие: "Ну, пошёл вразнос Сергеич!" - говорили об основательно загулявшем человеке. "В разнос" же в это время несколько скукожился, поскольку значительно сократилась и сама практика торговли в разнос.
То же и с другими приведёнными выше наречиями. Так, примера на раздельное написание "в раздрай" я вот что-то и не припомню. 
К чему это всё. Возвращаясь из профессионализмов в просторечную, а затем и общеупотребительную лексику, подобные слова играют, мне кажется, роль катализатора, влияя на восприятие  и употребление структурно однотипных слов по аналогии.

Comment: Из одного словаря на Грамоте.ру: Мотор пошел в разнос. Дизель работал вразнос. Это правильно, или нет?  Что-то запутались наши грамматики. А задача, скорее всего,  решается в общем, по одному принципу, а не для каждой пары слов в отдельности. И я не уверена, что  для этого  нужны такие сложные формулировки, как  "катализатор или  восприятие и употребление структурно однотипных слов по аналогии". Думается мне, что всё  намного проще и изящнее.